# Anti-derivative of $\frac{\exp(x)-1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series, indefinite-integrals

I am looking for the antiderivative of $$\frac{\exp(x)-1}{x}$$ I showed that it is equivalent to calculate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ but I can't find both of the solutions. If someone could help me I would very appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: For $x\ne0$, this is equivalent to compute the antiderivative of $e^x/x$, which cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: You can write the solution in terms of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) non-elementary function.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you cannot use the exponential integral function, leave it as you wrote
$$\int\frac{e^x-1}{x}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n \frac{x^n}{n!}>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac 1x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{e^x-x-1}x$$

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer !

Comment: @Odys. You are welcome ! You did a good job. Sooner or later, you will learn a lot about special functions and ... you will enjoy them. Cheers :-)